# HTML audio will not play when page opened by batch file

Tags: html, google-chrome, batch-file, audio

I have a web page that plays an audio file when I load it. When the page is opened by a windows batch file, the audio does not play. If the page is refreshed then the audio will play.

I have tried to make the page refresh once it has been opened by the batch file but I can't manage this without getting the page stuck in a reloading loop.

HTML Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>ALERT</title>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="130;url=index.html" />
    <iframe src="Sounds/silence.MP3" preload="auto" allow="autoplay" id="audio" style="display:none"></iframe>
    <audio autoplay>
        <source src="Sounds/AlertTone.MP3" preload="auto"type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
</head>
```

I expect the page to be opened by the batch file and the audio to play, but the audio doesn't play when the page is opened by the batch. It will only play if the page is refreshed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try With Vbscript :

```
@echo off
cmd /c ""C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\Empty Recycle Bin.htm" "
Rem Wait 5 Second
timeout /t 5
Echo WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys "{F5}">>Q.vbs
Cscript //nologo Q.vbs & Del "Q.vbs"
pause>nul
```

Comment: Thanks scientist_7, I will try this and let you know how I go.

Comment: This has fixed my issue. Thank you very much scientist_7